# Solve the Mosaic

Tags: grid-deduction

Mosaic is a Minesweeper-like puzzle based on a grid with a pixel-art picture hidden inside. Using logic alone, the solver determines which squares are painted and which should remain empty until the hidden picture is completely exposed.

Each puzzle consists of a grid containing clues in various places. The object is to reveal a hidden picture by painting the squares around each clue so that the number of painted squares, including the square with the clue, matches the value of the clue.

Rules of this puzzle can be found [here](http://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/fill-a-pix/techniques).

[image: mosaic]

Click to enlarge.

<sup>Created by [this](https://github.com/MouseEvent/Mosaic) tool.</sup>

Comment: @Deusovi Hope this fits the requirements.

Comment: Can we have a CSV?

Comment: @boboquack I'm out of my office already. I'll post it tomorrow.

Comment: This seems tedious.

Comment: I have to question the attitude behind a puzzle like this.  It can't have taken more than 2 minutes to load an image into this generator and post the output, and we're supposed to spend an hour repeating the same elementary logical deductions hundreds of times?

Comment: @paramesis I'll try to use smaller images in the future.

Comment: @Mordechai Smaller isn't the only point. This sort of puzzle is more interesting if it requires some non-trivial deduction. I worked through this one to see how it would go, and it was pretty much all "obvious" things: find a cell whose state is obviously determined by something nearby, fill it in, repeat.

Comment: @Gareth I understand. I should've placed the clues in a more scattered manner that requires more logical reasoning instead of a checkerboard layout. I think I'll delete this and post a better later.

Comment: As I said in a comment to Dr Xorile's answer, I don't think you need delete it.

Comment: The trouble is, I'm not sure the puzzle format *allows* for complicated chains of logical deduction. (And if it does, it certainly won't be making a recognizable image.)

Comment: @Deusovi It definitly does have advanced complexity as you can see at [Advanced Logic](http://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/fill-a-pix/techniques) from ConceptisPuzzles.com. They're example a lower level, but deeper levels could be created and still be uniquely solveable.

Comment: As a fan of this type of puzzle, and logic puzzles in general, it is definitely the case that really "chewy" examples exist.  I don't think that interesting puzzles are incompatible with a recognisable pattern:  the process of making one of these puzzles is that you start out with every square having a number (which makes it trivially easy) then remove numbers until it becomes difficult, but still solvable without guesswork.  This is the art of puzzle design, and can be done with any background pattern which is a mix of black and white squares.  I don't think this question is a good example.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I know, I'm already doing it this way. You can check out [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51261/my-featured-entry) question and my [github repo](https://github.com/mordechaim/Mosaic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is

> Puzzling, with a nice little logo on top.

Image:

> [image]

Comment: I was working on this concurrently with you but got there second. I've added an image for you.

Comment: Thanks. As was said in the previous comments, it was a bit easy. Just trace the 0s and you are 95% done. The puzzle itself has potential, but a grid like that is obviously automated

Comment: @DrXorile I agree i made a mistake for making this so easy. The automation is actually a program i wrote. I'll probably delete this post and create better of this type in the future.

Comment: Don't delete it; deletion is for non-puzzles and plagiarism and outstandingly terrible puzzles and the like, not for puzzles that turn out to be a bit tedious to solve. If you have a program that solves these as well as one that makes them, you can make them harder while still auto-generating them by the following method: start out with every clue present, and then delete clues at random until you can no longer delete them without making the problem unsolvable. The result is a puzzle that's *only just solvable* given the clues it contains.

Comment: Good job on the automation then. Certainly creating interesting challenges automatically is of interest. But in some ways making the automation find challenging logic would enhance the puzzle. I would leave this one up, as it helps create better puzzles which is what this is all about in the end.

Comment: (Note: the automatic procedure I described typically produces puzzles that are at least somewhat difficult, but difficult is still not the same thing as interesting. Guaranteeing that a puzzle is interesting is harder :-).)

Comment: Well unique and minimal is normally enough. If the algorithm can keep removing clues until the removal of any additional clue would result in multiple solutions that would probably be enough...

Comment: @DrXorile That would be enough to create a valid puzzle yes, but as Gareth said, that doesn't necessarily mean the puzzle is going to be interesting.  There's a craft to arranging clues such that they interact in unexpected ways.  I'd much rather solve a puzzle cleverly crafted by a human mind than some random combination of clues that just happen to be valid as determined by a computer program, just as I'd rather read a book written by a human author than a collection of random sentences.