# My featured entry

Tags: visual, grid-deduction

Mosaic is a Minesweeper-like puzzle based on a grid with a pixel-art picture hidden inside. Using logic alone, the solver determines which squares are painted and which should remain empty until the hidden picture is completely exposed.

Each puzzle consists of a grid containing clues in various places. The object is to reveal a hidden picture by painting the squares around each clue so that the number of painted squares, including the square with the clue, matches the value of the clue.

Rules of this puzzle can be found [here](http://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/fill-a-pix/techniques).

[image: mosaic]

CSV version (`filename.csv` - open with excel):

```
,4,,,,,,,4,,,,,,4,,,,0,
,,,,3,3,,,,,,3,,,,4,,,,
3,,0,,0,,3,,3,0,0,,,0,,,,,0,
,,,,1,,5,,,,,,,,3,,,,,
3,,,,,,4,,,,,,0,,,3,3,,,
,,0,1,,,6,,,0,1,,,,,,,,0,
3,,,,,,,,,,2,,,1,3,,,3,,
,,0,,,2,,,,2,,,3,2,,,4,,,2
4,,,,,,,5,,5,,6,,,,,6,6,,4
,,,,,,5,,5,,,4,,,,3,,,,4
,,4,6,4,,,6,,,,2,,3,,,,6,6,
3,,,,3,2,2,,,3,,1,,0,,,,,,
,,2,,,,,,,,,,0,0,3,,,3,,
,3,,,,0,,,,3,,1,,,3,,3,,0,
,,,,,,,6,,,1,,,,,,,,,
,3,0,,1,,,,,2,,,,,,,3,0,0,
,,,,,,,3,,3,,,0,0,,,,,,
3,,,0,,,3,,3,,,0,,0,,,,,0,
4,,3,,,,,0,,,5,,,,5,,3,,,
,,,3,,,2,,,,,,,3,,,,,,0
```

Plain text version:

```
  4             4           4       0   
        3 3           3       4         
3   0   0   3   3 0 0     0         0   
        1   5               3           
3           4           0     3 3       
    0 1     6     0 1               0   
3                   2     1 3     3     
    0     2       2     3 2     4     2 
4             5   5   6         6 6   4 
            5   5     4       3       4 
    4 6 4     6       2   3       6 6   
3       3 2 2     3   1   0             
    2                   0 0 3     3     
  3       0       3   1     3   3   0   
              6     1                   
  3 0   1         2             3 0 0   
              3   3     0 0             
3     0     3   3     0   0         0   
4   3         0     5       5   3       
      3     2             3           0
```

---

<sup>Created and tested with [this](https://github.com/MouseEvent/Mosaic) tool of mine.</sup>

Comment: It's nice to see someone include a CSV, but can you also post a version with just numbers offset by spaces? It's quite hard to do this puzzle on a phone as it stands.

Comment: @boboquack Like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OHH

Here's an answer. It's

> a 'metapuzzle'

The picture.

> [image: solution]
>  It's a jigsaw puzzle piece made of jigsaw pieces.

Comment: You got the picture right. I don't want to spoil it, somebody will eventually figure it out.

Comment: It's a jigsaw puzzle.

Comment: Oh is it that obvious? I was thinking it was a jigsaw puzzle, then going: "Nah, it can't be a jigsaw puzzle, it's gotta be some logo or something."

Comment: Yes. But with a twist. Look at the
title.

Comment: Well, it's a reference to some post on the meta site.

Comment: @Mordechai Is this the correct answer? I mean, I don't think it is, but...

Comment: Nope, in fact it's a "featured" post on meta, as the title says... Ok now i spoiled it.

Comment: It's not something you think right away. It's a little out of the box.

Comment: @Mordechai I've gotten it. Should've thought of this sooner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57659/discussion-between-awesomepi-and-mordechai).